# What underlying semantic notions connect 'mēnsa' to the PIE *me-?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

> [[U Texas :]](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1235.html)   Pokorny Etymon: 3. mē-, m-e-t-   'to measure'
>   Semantic Field: [to Measure](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/iedocctr/ie-ling/ie-sem/SR/SR_MS.html)
>
> [...]   **Italic:**   Latin:   mēnsa
>
> [ [Wiktionary :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensa#Latin) ]
>
> 1. a table
> 2. a table of food; meal, course, feast
> 3. an altar (sacrificial table)
> 4. vocative singular of mēnsa

2 reminds me of [the semantic shift of the English 'meal'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=meal&allowed_in_frame=0), from this same PIE root to >repast or time for eating<. But what explains the semantic shift to 1 or 3?
Is it as direct and simple as the fact that tables were used by the Romans to eat?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but I've been doing some research: the noun _mensa_ matches the pasive participle of the verb _metior_ (to meassure). That seems to confirm the idea of a link between both. (And may be the reason why scholars mention such a link).

Answer (score 5):

The entry for this word in the *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic languages* (2008), by Michiel de Vaan, may provide some illumination.

De Vaan says that *mensa* has an Umbrian cognate *mefa* that is supposed to have the meaning "a certain sacrificial object, maybe cake".

As Rafael said in a comment, the derivation from the verb meaning 'measure', *met(ior),* is supposed to have occurred via a participle form. A sacrifice of food could be described fairly literally as "a thing measured out". De Vaan suggests that

> In Latin, the meaning then shifted from the offering itself to the object on which the offerings were placed.